# Call a function after x seconds while keep running rest of the program in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, timer

I have a program in which I want to call a function after x seconds or minutes while keep running rest of the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run new thread:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono> 

using namespace std;

// The function we want to execute on the new thread.
void task(int sleep)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(sleep));
    cout << "print after " << sleep << " seconds" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    // Constructs the new thread and runs it. Does not block execution.
    thread t1(task, 5);

    // Do other things...

    // Makes the main thread wait for the new thread to finish execution, therefore blocks its own execution.
    t1.join();
}
```

Comment: just added an infinite loop inside task function and worked well for me. Thank alot @Elizaveta